# How do I install aiohttp on Windows 10 with miniconda?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, anaconda

What I tried:

```
C:\Users\stiv\miniconda3\Scripts>conda install -c conda-forge aiohttp                                                                  Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

and with pip:

```
C:\Users\stiv\miniconda3\Scripts>pip install aiohttp    
                                                                               WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.  
                   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiohttp/                                                        WARNING: 
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiohttp/                                                        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiohttp/                                                        
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiohttp/                                                       
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiohttp/                                                        Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/aiohttp/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/aiohttp/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping                                                                                                     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp (from versions: none)                                           ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp    
                                                                                 
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.                     
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

How can I fix it, or are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when certain libs are missing from PATH look in to the following post that has instructions on what you need to add to PATH https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1139